# Tensorflow on Anaconda error cannot find cudnn64_6.dll

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, spyder, cudnn

I am having a problem with Tensorflow running on Spyder. When I installed it in cmd, it had the same problem that it couldn't find the path to cudnn64_6.dll, and so I added pathway to it and it seemed to import. Then, I installed the theano library and the keras and it seemed ok, then when I tried to import the keras library in spider, I got this message:

[image]

I have Cuda v8.0 and it should have that with it, at least I am told. I have installed all the drivers and downloaded the cudnn v6.0 for Cuda 8.0 and have added enough paths but still no luck. Where have I gone wrong?

[image]

Comment: CUDNN is not distributed in the CUDA toolkit. You must download and install it separately. And please mind your language. Some decorum is expected here.

Comment: _A picture tells more then 1000 words_ does not fare well on SO. Do not use pictures, copy the text of your error messages verbatim into your question. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Its Ok I just had to get rid of some environment paths and restart. My bad